# send id to a modal with php or ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanna assign a modal to a button , that shows a warning to the client.
the warning is about : are you sure delete that.
my problem is about send the id to modal with ajax or something else and i am newbe with ajax or javascript so my code is Incomplete

here is my button :

```
    <button title="delete" data-modal="md-just-me" data-id=<?= $row->id_post; ?> class="delete-post"></button>
```

here is my script (Incomplete):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.delete-post').click(function() {
  var btn = $(this);
  var id = btn.data('id');
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"",
    data : {
  id : id
     },
    success: function(msg){
        alert( 'ok' ) ;
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

i want the button and modal in same page

and this is my model :

```html
<div class="md-modal md-just-me" id="md-just-me">
   <?php $id = $_GET['id'];?>
   <div class="md-content">
    <h2>warning</h2>
    
    
   <p>do you want continue? </p>
     <p>
     <button class="btn btn-danger md-close">close</button>
     <a href="<?php base_url(post/delete).$id ?>">yes im suer</button>
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You don't want to use php to show the modal, that would require you to refresh the page for the modal to appear.  You want to click them button, show the modal, and then when they confirm the modal, THEN you make an ajax request.

Comment: yes i know about that . but i need id_post for the tag <a> in modal and i dont know how send it

Comment: and yeah when i click the button the modal is showen up but with no id

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've whipped up an example [here](https://codepen.io/SpringsTea/pen/vQKWbp).
Basically, I grab the id of the item that calls the modal, and set an attribute in the modal so that it can be accessed from the confirmation button:

```
var modalid = $(this).closest('.modal').data('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a excellent library called [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) that can ease this process for you. First, you need to add the library.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Now, if you want a confirmation message, all you got do is add the following code.

```
$('.delete-post').click(function() {
    swal({
        title: 'Warning!',
        text: "Do you want continue?",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        cancelButtonText:"No",
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, I am sure!'
    }).then((result) => {
        // If true, then call your `ajax` here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want send id to modal you can do like this code i use bootstrap

this my button in my each row:

```
<a href="#" data-target="#dell-one-modal"
data-toggle="modal"
class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger p-1 identifyingdell-one"
data-idman="<?php echo htmlentities($rows['terms_id']); ?>">
<i class="icofont-ui-delete" data-toggle="tooltip"
data-placement="right" title="delete"></i></a>
```

and this my bootstap modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="dell-one-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="dell-one-aria" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title text-danger schms-font-size-14 font-weight-bold" id="dell-one-aria">تایید
نهایی عملیات حذف دانش آموز</h5>
<button type="button" class="close ml-1"
data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<form method="get" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
<div class="modal-body text-secondary schms-font-size-12 text-justify">
برای <span class="text-danger">حذف</span> دانش آموز روی تایید کلیک کنید.بعد از <span class="text-danger">حذف</span> هیچ راهی برای <span class="text-success">بازیابی</span> اطلاعات وجود ندارد.
<hr>
<span class="text-muted schms-font-size-10"><span class="text-warning">راهنمایی</span> : باید دانش آموز متناظر با کلید <i class="icofont-ui-delete text-danger"></i> را انتخاب کنید.</span>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddellval" id="hiddenValue" value=""/>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer mx-auto">
<button type="submit" name="dell-one-submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">تایید
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info mx-2" data-dismiss="modal">انصراف
</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

i put my form in modal , you can put modal in your form

and this javascript code send id to modal , put id to the hidden input

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".identifyingdell-one").click(function () {
            var my_id_value = $(this).data('idman');
            $(".modal-body #hiddenValue").val(my_id_value);
        })
    });
    </script>
```